# Android Scroll view Image and text

Tags: android, scrollview

I am solving a problem with image and text in one scroll view. The main problem is, that I get different image height from server side . But the place with image should be all the time same. 
Now the height of image place is dynamic. The text should be scrollable with the image.

Is there any possibility how to make the image height static?

Thank you!

[image]

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/article_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="4" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/article_image_back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/sipka_l" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/article_image"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/article_image_next"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/sipka_p" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/image_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/tran_dark_gray"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/size_8"
                android:textAppearance="@style/xsmallLight" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@color/opaq_light"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/size_16" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/article_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_12"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/normalBold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/article_body"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/xsmall" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the ImageView with a fixed width and height it will remain static all the time.

Try something like:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
/>
```

Put this `ImageView` inside a `ScrollView` and ofcourse put your `TextView` inside the same ScrollView.

Comment: Thank you response. But for every screen resolution will be the same height, won't be? Is there any possibilities to define it with  ratio coefficient for example 30% of whole screen not for whole Scroll view? Because image 50dp will be small on high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use layout weights for your linearlayout.  Set the width to 0 and let the weight determine actual size.  Setting weight to 0.33 each gives each images 1/3 of the screen.
Or you could set one to 0.5 and the others to 0.25 each or whatever makes sense for your app.

Set the  3 images as:

```
      <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/article_image_back"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0.33"
           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
           android:src="@drawable/sipka_l" />
```